# Changing a Smarty value from a plugin function?

Tags: php, plugins, smarty

I have a plugin function which should be used to modify a given Smarty variable which is an array.

After reading the docs, it looks like this should be the way to do it:

```
$var = &$smarty->getTemplateVars($params['var']);
$var['blah'] = 'aaa';
```

... but it doesn't work. The array, as seen by other template code after the call to this plugin function, sees the array unmodified.

So, how can a plugin function modify a template variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless someone figures out a solution, it looks like it cannot be done in a "function" plugin type. It can be done in a "modifier", though.